# Specific directories with problems with passive / port

Tags: iis, ftp, passive-mode

I've a very strange problem boring me since a long time, and I dont find any clue to check what's the matter.

I've a ftp root with a lot of directory without any problem.

In a specific directory, I've a website containing several directories. On each directory, I've no problem on the root, but on the subdirectories, I can only download in Passive Mode, and upload on Port Mode, so I've to switch every time between modes to work.

```
+ Site1 > no problem
  - directories > no problem
    - subfolders > no problem
+ Site2 > no problem
  - directories > no problem
    - subfolders > DL in PASV, UL in PORT
```

As all sites are on the same IIS, all directories have the same privileges, I really stuck on what can explain that problem.

I would really enjoy if someone one day encountered the same problem and found a solution...

Thank you :)

Edit : a trace of an attempt to Download in PORT mode :

```
[15:56:28] [R] Connecting to x.x.x.x -> IP=x.x.x.x PORT=21
[15:56:28] [R] Connected to x.x.x.x
[15:56:28] [R] 220 Microsoft FTP Service
[15:56:28] [R] USER x
[15:56:28] [R] 331 Password required
[15:56:28] [R] PASS (hidden)
[15:56:28] [R] 230 User logged in.
[15:56:28] [R] SYST
[15:56:28] [R] 215 Windows_NT
[15:56:28] [R] FEAT
[15:56:28] [R] 211-Extended features supported:
[15:56:28] [R]  LANG EN*
[15:56:28] [R]  UTF8
[15:56:28] [R]  AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
[15:56:28] [R]  PBSZ
[15:56:28] [R]  PROT C;P;
[15:56:28] [R]  CCC
[15:56:28] [R]  HOST
[15:56:28] [R]  SIZE
[15:56:28] [R]  MDTM
[15:56:28] [R]  REST STREAM
[15:56:28] [R] 211 END
[15:56:28] [R] OPTS UTF8 ON
[15:56:28] [R] 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
[15:56:28] [R] PWD
[15:56:28] [R] 257 "/" is current directory.
[15:56:28] [R] CWD /site2/dir/subdir/
[15:56:28] [R] 250 CWD command successful.
[15:56:28] [R] PWD
[15:56:28] [R] 257 "/site2/dir/subdir" is current directory.
[15:56:28] [R] Listening on PORT: 59644, Waiting for connection.
[15:56:28] [R] PORT 192,168,212,170,232,252
[15:56:28] [R] 200 PORT command successful.
[15:56:28] [R] LIST -al
[15:56:28] [R] 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
[15:56:28] [R] 226 Transfer complete.
[15:56:28] [R] List Complete: 5 KB in 0,05 seconds (5,3 KB/s)
[15:56:36] [R] TYPE A
[15:56:36] [R] 200 Type set to A.
[15:56:36] [R] SIZE file.doc
[15:56:36] [R] 213 155
[15:56:36] [R] MDTM file.doc
[15:56:36] [R] 213 20190221173054
[15:56:38] [R] PORT 192,168,212,170,232,253
[15:56:38] [R] 200 PORT command successful.
[15:56:38] [R] RETR file.doc
[15:56:38] [R] 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
[15:56:38] [R] 550 The specified network name is no longer available. 
[15:56:38] [R] Transfer Failed: file.doc
[15:56:38] Transfer queue completed
[15:56:38] Transferred 0 Files (0 bytes) in 2 seconds (0,0 KB/s)
[15:56:38] 1 File Failed
```

Comment: Can you post the error message of your FTP client?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, this may related with the antivirus interference.

If you have enable the  antivirus interference in the server, I suggest you could try to disable it and try again.